# Concatenate value in each column based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation

Hello I need to concatenate the columns depending on whether the rows are null or have any value.
I.e. I have data like this

[image]

And I need get data like this

[image]

The problem is that the columns I want to join will be more than 50 and for each I have to check if there is a blank or a number in that column and row.

Can you help me with this please?

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/8422953)

Comment: Should only that 3 Value columns involved, or you may add some others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you asked for a VBA solution, please try the next code. It will process as many `Value` columns will be, and returns the processing result two columns after the last one. Using arrays, the code will be very fast even for a large range:

```
Sub ConcatenateWithValues()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, lastCol As Long, arr, arrH, arrFin
   Dim strConc As String, i As Long, j As Long
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet   'use here the sheet you need
   lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.Rows.count).End(xlUp).row          'last row on column A:A
   lastCol = sh.cells(1, sh.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'last column on the first row
   
   arr = sh.Range("A1", sh.cells(lastR, lastCol)).Value         'place the whole range in an array, for faster iteration
   arrH = sh.Range("A1", sh.cells(1, lastCol)).Value            'Place headers in an array
   ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 2)                       'Redim the array to contain the processing result
   arrFin(1, 1) = arrH(1, 1): arrFin(1, 2) = "Concatenate_Value"'Place the headers in the array
   For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
        For j = 2 To lastCol 'build the necessary concatenation
            If arr(i, j) <> "" Then strConc = strConc & arrH(1, j) & ":" & arr(i, j) & ";"
        Next
        arrFin(i, 1) = arr(i, 1): arrFin(i, 2) = left(strConc, Len(strConc) - 1) 'remove the last ";" character
        strConc = ""         'reinitialize the string keeping row concatenation
   Next i
   'Drop the processed array content at once:
   sh.cells(1, lastCol + 2).Resize(UBound(arrFin), 2).Value = arrFin
End Sub
```

Comment: @Kateřina Chábová Glad I could help! I added some more comments for easy understanding what the code does...

Answer (score 0):

With ***Microsoft-365*** you may try-

```
=TEXTJOIN("; ",TRUE,FILTER(IF($B$2:$D$5<>"",$B$1:$D$1&":"&$B$2:$D$5,""),$A$2:$A$5=F2))
```

[image]